# Is $\frac{k!!}{j!!(k-j)!!}\leq\frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}$ for all integers $j$ and $k$, where $0\leq j\leq k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, summation

For all integers $j$ and $k$, where $0\leq j\leq k$, is the inequality

$\frac{k!!}{j!!(k-j)!!}\leq\frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}$

true?

I have a feeling that it is and it would be helpful to me if it is, but I do not know how to go about proving it besides cancelling out the factors that are on both the left and right sides.

Eventually, I want to show that $\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{k!!}{j!!(k-j)!!}\leq\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}=2^k$.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial, you will find interesting relation between double factorials and factorials, namely, for odd values
$$(2k-1)!!=\frac{2^{-k} (2 k)!}{k!}$$ and $$(2k)!!=2^k k!$$ for even values. This could help you significantly for your first question.

For your last question, it is a problem I worked a long time ago in the area of statistical thermodynamics and, for your left hand side term, I arrived, for the summation, to an ugly formula which is
$$\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-(-1)^k-1\right)} \pi ^{\frac{(-1)^k}{2}} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{k+2}{2}\right) \left(2 \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1-k}{2};\frac{3}{2};-1\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{k+3}{2}\right)-\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{k+3}{2};-1\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{k+3}{2}\right)}+2^{k/2}$$ that I have never been able to simplify. This is alway smaller than $2^k$.

Plotting the ratio of this monster to $2^k$ as a function of $k$, the points align on two curves (one for odd values of $k$, the other for even values of $k$) which shows,as one could expect, an exponential decrease.

As Newb wrote in his answer, take care that $j>2$ is a required condition.

Comment: Wow! That formula is a bit nastier than I desired, but thank you very much. Why doesn't the inequality work for $j\leq2$? For $2=j\leq k$, $LHS=\frac{k}{2}$ and $RHS=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ so $LHS\leq RHS$ as $2\leq k$. For $1=j\leq k$, $RHS=k$ and $LHS=\frac{k(k-2)!!}{(k-1)!!}$ so $LHS\leq RHS$ as $(k-2)!!\leq (k-1)!!$. For $0=j\leq k$, $LHS=1$ and $RHS=1$. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You mention that Newb agreed with $2\leq j$ but their answer seems to have disappeared.